# Java regex string sub pattern exclusion

Tags: java, regex

I have two map-like java strings.

```
   String msg =  "{Name:\"Mouse\",abc:\"123\",c:0,trash:\"12345\"}"
    string msg2 ="{Name:\"Mouse\",abc:\"123\",c:0,trash:\"10005\"}"
```

I have to do Java regex to just compare these two strings and return true if both are same except for the trash key's value. Apparently in the above two strings, comparing them would return false since trash values are different. How do I accomplish with regex without typecasting?

Kindly point me to the right direction. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, regex is not for comparison of strings. Why are you using regex here? strings appears to be JSON document so use proper library.

Comment: Replace the trash key with some default value and compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove trash entry in both strings before comparison, e.g.

```
     String p = ",trash:\".*\"";
     boolean res = msg.replaceAll(p, "").equals(msg2.replaceAll(p, ""));
```

Comment: The `.*` should be `.*?`, so it'll stop at first `"`.